# could not execute process 'target\debug\lat5.exe` (never executed)

Tags: rust

I am newbie in Rust prog. language, although I knew PHP & Javascript. The problem is in this simple beginner code :

```
fn main() {
    let x = 4;            // immutable by default, 
    println!("x = {}", x);
    let x = 5;            // Redefining x
    println!("x = {}", x);
}
```

According to a youtube tutorial(Tech With Tim) it can be run (showed in his monitor), but when I try to compile and run (cargo run), it can't be run and show this error :
"error: could not execute process `target\debug\lat5.exe` (never executed)

Caused by:
Access is denied. (os error 5)",
and Avira tell that is a HUER/APC threat....?

Comment: Add an exclusion path in Avira for your development directory.

Comment: Thank you pigeonhands, I just realize that's caused by Avira. It's really make me confused.